# Can't compile iwlwifi module in Linux

Tags: c, linux, makefile, wifi

I'm trying to build `iwlwifi` module manually and for my needs.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-fixes.git/tree/net/wireless/

When I run Makefile as `make`, I get:

```
subcmd-util.h: In function ‘xrealloc’:
subcmd-util.h:58:31: error: pointer ‘ptr’ may be used after ‘realloc’ [-Werror=use-after-free]
   58 |                         ret = realloc(ptr, 1);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
subcmd-util.h:52:21: note: call to ‘realloc’ here
   52 |         void *ret = realloc(ptr, size);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
subcmd-util.h:56:23: error: pointer ‘ptr’ may be used after ‘realloc’ [-Werror=use-after-free]
   56 |                 ret = realloc(ptr, size);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
subcmd-util.h:52:21: note: call to ‘realloc’ here
   52 |         void *ret = realloc(ptr, size);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [/data/iwlwifi-fixes/tools/build/Makefile.build:97: /data/iwlwifi-fixes/tools/objtool/help.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:59: /data/iwlwifi-fixes/tools/objtool/libsubcmd-in.o] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:63: /data/iwlwifi-fixes/tools/objtool/libsubcmd.a] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:69: objtool] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1349: tools/objtool] Error 2
```

Why is it? How to fix it?

Comment: Did you not `ptr = ret;` after determining that `ret != NULL`? Or have you already stored other pointer values into the previous memory block, before reallocation, which you later dereference?

Comment: The code requires an older compiler version.  [Answered here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709671/linux-kernel-5-15-54-compilation-errors-with-gcc-12-1).  The issue was also [reported here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2043113).

Comment: @DrewDormann 1) I can't use an older compiler - I'm on Arch Linux. 2) there's no `-Werror=use-after-free` or anything similar anywhere in this repo either.